# Mysql how to join related table by '[id, anotherId]' format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with field related_table_ids (example value `["1110663703","1958153258"]`).
Tried join related table by query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.table 
INNER JOIN related_table ON related_table.id IN (
  SUBSTRING(table.related_table_ids, 2, (LENGTH(table.related_table_ids) - 2))
)
```

But that doesn't work, returns 0 rows. help pls!

**table**

```
id | related_table_ids
---------
1  | ["1110663703","1958153258"]
2  | ["2032453865"]
3  | ["1304031696"]
```

**related_table**

```
id 
---------
1110663703
1958153258
2032453865
1304031696
```

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE script for `table`. Does `related_table_ids` column is JSON type column?

Comment: yes, column is json. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bc91e0bebb60b375443a89c9d64d2d5e)

Comment: There is a problem. The values in JSON array are strings whereas the values in related_table are integers. So you cannot search the array for the value, the datatype won't be converted rather then in regular compare, the values from related_table must be converted to strings and wrapped with dquote chars which will degrade the performance. I recommend you to convert the JSON array elements to numbers (remove all dquote chars) which will allow direct compare in JSON_CONTAINS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=9a052ecf7ed72640517c20993b40982a

Comment: Anycase this will be slow due to cartesian - MariaDB does not implement JSON datatype, and it have no multi-valued indexes. Also MariaDB have no JSON_TABLE function. You may test the next - parse JSON array to single values in recursive CTE then join - this method may use index by `related_table (id)` at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`related_table_ids` looks like a json string. Therefore, you can use the [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) function.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
JOIN related_table rt ON JSON_CONTAINS(related_table_ids, CONCAT('"', rt.id, '"'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dcfe917803a25353218e705af6d8218)

Comment: That seems like should work, but i get infinity processing of query. dbfiddle is correct.

Comment: This is not infinity processing, just many rows. But in migration i get error - "General error: 4037 Unexpected end of JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_contains'" <br/>
query - `UPDATE table JOIN related_table ON JSON_CONTAINS(table.related_table_ids, CONCAT('\"', related_table.id, '\"')) SET table.field = related_table.field`;

Comment: Thank you! There was fields with value - ''. I resolved that by `CASE WHEN related_table_ids = '' THEN '[]' ELSE related_table_ids END`.